# Default RatingBar set icon issue according to step size (Get RatingBar value is ok)

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am suffering from set step size problem using Android default RatingBar.

**Code**

```
private RatingBar rb;
private TextView tvSetRatingBar;
private Button btnGetRatingBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rb = findViewById(R.id.rb);
    tvSetRatingBar = findViewById(R.id.tvSetRatingBar);
    btnGetRatingBar = findViewById(R.id.btnGetRatingBar);

    btnGetRatingBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String strGetData = String.valueOf(rb.getRating());
            tvSetRatingBar.setText("Get Rating = " + strGetData);
        }
    });
}
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:numStars="6"
    android:stepSize=".1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSetRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="Set RatingBar"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGetRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="Get RatingBar"
    android:padding="10dp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**output** [image]

**Problem**

You can see in above image getRating value is set in TextView is ok but RatingBar icon is not set proper it's always set 2.5.I have use default RatingBar.

android:stepSize=".1" set in Layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to `RatingBar`

```
android:secondaryProgressTint="#00000000"
```

If you this attribute with `RatingBar`, it will work only with **API >=21**.

However, to make it work for all versions, use `AppCompatRatingBar` like below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:isIndicator="false"
            android:numStars="6"
            android:stepSize=".1"
            app:secondaryProgressTint="#00000000"
           />
```

Add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your root layout.

And don't forget to add `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:X.X.X'`(replace X with the latest version) in your app level gradle.

Comment: sorry, clicked by mistake. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Sorry but when i use your above code using AppCompatRatingBar is show error like Error:error: attribute 'com.example.android.ratingbarandcalenderviewdemo:secondaryProgressTint' not found.

Comment: @DileepPatel Check my updated answer. And also in your activity's java code, it should extend `AppCompatActivity` not just `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks it's working as i accepted also i update your code please check

Comment: please update your code so i will accept your answer.

Comment: @DileepPatel No. You should not use `android:***` because it will not work with older versions. You should use `AppCompatRatingBar` with `app:secondaryProgressTint` to support all versions. I hope Android Studio is showing you the warning there.

Comment: Ok but in my gradle i was set  minSdkVersion 15 , but it's show same error for using   app:secondaryProgressTint="#00000000" ??

Comment: @DileepPatel The version I am talking about is the devices having version < 21. Your device is having version >= 21, thats why its working properly on your side. But if you run in lower version devices, it will not work.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: yes my device is nexus 5 but how to support it's all devices version like below <21 and >21 using app:secondaryProgressTint="#00000000".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159379/discussion-between-faa-and-dileep-patel).

Answer (score -1):

Ratingbar stepsize have some properties. Its nothing but a factor by which you increase ratings on **RatingBar**. If you want ratings to be displayed like 3.5 or 4.5, you can use stepSize as **0.5**. Incase, you want ratings like 3.1 or 4.3, you can have stepSize like 0.1.

Happy coding!!

Comment: please check once more my above layout code i already set step size 0.1

Comment: @ankitpatidar i post based on i used so many times in my project. and above post have documentation on android developer account. so think about before you post anything.

Comment: Sorry #Hemant Sir, i understand it was written there. but its not a solution for problem . Thats why i wrote comment.